# How to have a streaming video in a html canvas ? where I can draw lines on it?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video-streaming

How to have a streaming video in a html canvas ?
Right now I have an image.
I have made the canvas to draw a few diagrams on in and get the coordinates of all the lines i've drawn.
But here all i have is an image. I want a live streaming video as my background instead of the image.

The code:

Html part:

```
<canvas id=canvas width="1000" height="470"></canvas>
```

javascript part:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
img = new Image;                
ctx.lineWidth = 7;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#c00';
ctx.fillStyle="#F9E5E5";
ctx.lineCap = 'round';




img.onload = start;
img.src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Solid_black.svg/2000px-Solid_black.svg.png';
```

Comment: you want to have 1) a canvas for your background, 2) a video playing on that canvas, and 3) you want to be able to draw on the canvas..... and you have showed us sample code for how to draw a line and load an image... that's hardly relevant to the request.. what have you tried and which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: You can take a look there: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Manipulating_video_using_canvas

Or generally speaking start from looking from "render video in canvas"